# Not able to pass # in my password using autoIT

Tags: selenium, autoit

I am using Autoit for authentication window in chrome using selenium. My Password Contains special character, but # is not getting entered in my Password.

My password is " D#e$r@2016"

Could anyone please help.

Comment: Please publish your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send keys not working selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770697/send-keys-not-working-selenium-webdriver-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Send() to pass a string like "password#99@TT"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622171/how-to-use-send-to-pass-a-string-like-password99tt)

Answer (score 1):

The following code may helps, # has special meaning in auto IT. so it should be escaped using braces.

Method 1: `send(" D{#}e$r@2016")`

If you send all characters as raw then set the flag value to 1. By default, the flag is 0.

Method 2: `send(" D#e$r@2016",1)`