# How to use Send() to pass a string like "password#99@TT"?

Tags: autoit

I am using AutoIt to handle a browser authentication window which Selenium can't access. Below is my AutoIt code.

```
Send("demo")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("password#99@TT")
```

It only sends `password#`; remaining characters `99@TT` are skipped. Please let me know how to pass such a string via [`Send()` command](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm).

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation of AutoIt about the `Send()` function you have an option to send RAW.

See more documentation [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)

In your case, I would try `Send("password#99@TT", 1)`

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

You can try also `Send("password{#}99@TT")`

I have found just now this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688776/8179099), I think it can help you.

Comment: user4157124    ,, Thanks a lot ... Send("password#99@TT", 1)) is works for me .. Now it not skipping any characters