# Want to pass Send("sun@123!") as a string but it is not working

Tags: autoit

I want to pass `Send("sun@123!")` as a string and tried the below script :

```
Send("abhishek.gaur") 
Send("{TAB}") 
Send("sun@123!") 
Send("{TAB}") 
Send("{ENTER}")
```

It always skips! From the password string leading not to run `Send("{ENTER}")` step defined at the end of the script.

Comment: read the [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) - especially about the `flag` part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Send() to pass a string like "password#99@TT"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622171/how-to-use-send-to-pass-a-string-like-password99tt)

Answer (score 0):

Used Send("sun@123{!}") and acheived it.