# Selenium SendKeys is not working properly

Tags: selenium

When I fill the value for the text box as `"700091495001458"`,

the selenium is removing some of the characters in the string and then filling the value as `"70009140018"`

```
search.getElement().sendKeys("700091495001458")
```

but it is working fine in MacOs

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G1611
```

but is is not working properly in aws ec2-instance GNU/Linux
I'm using `ChromeDriver 2.34.522932`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send keys not working selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770697/send-keys-not-working-selenium-webdriver-python)

Comment: Add some wait before and after entering text... and try

Comment: Please give more information, like the version of browser and chromedriver  on Mac and Linux,   did the textbox bind keyboard event to do the legal checking after user type each character,  more code before the sendKeys()  to help us to learn your script operation procedure.