# ElementNotInteractableException:Error when setting a value within td element using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, setattribute

I am trying to enter the number 1 into the MasterPack boxes within this table but get an error telling me it is not interactable.
[image]

My code looked like this and produced the element not interactable error

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="asnPick_order_0_itemInfo_TABLE"]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]')
.send_keys("1")
```

The HTML for the table is here, I am trying to edit the MasterPack cell, so the line in between 125 and 1. The cell in the table I am trying to edit has no attributes and is blank. The text for the other cells is not listed under an attribute it is just there inbetween the   tags.

```
<tr><td class="">0001</td>
<td class="">1022-0221-00</td>
<td class="">1004850854</td>
<td class="">8809490582667</td>
<td class="">19</td>
<td class="htAutocomplete">Each<div class="htAutocompleteArrow">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td class="">125</td>
<td class=""></td>
<td class="">1</td>
<td class="htAutocomplete">Each<div class="htAutocompleteArrow">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td class="">D480 3-STAGE TRUE HEPA AIR PURIFIER</td>
<td class=""><a class="no-border" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><div class="screen-reader-only">Delete</div></a></td></tr>
```

I found that I can successfully click on the box using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="asnPick_order_0_itemInfo_TABLE"]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]').click()
```

I believe this is a dynamic table because
When I click on any cell it changes the HTML to show the class = "current highlight" I have a line of code that successfully clicks on the master pack cell. The element not intractable error occurs when I try to send keys
I need to figure out how to edit the numbers without a tag, for example here is the html of another cell that already had text in it.

```
<td class="">8809490582667</td>
```

I need to edit those numbers, but in the master pack cell where its blank without getting a element not interactable error.

Here is the html from after I click the master pack box, I don't think clicking it is necessary to enter text but then again, I don't know.

```
<tr><td class="">0001</td>
<td class="">1022-0221-00</td>
<td class="">1004850854</td>
<td class="">8809490582667</td>
<td class="">19</td>
<td class="htAutocomplete">Each<div class="htAutocompleteArrow">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td class="">125</td>
<td class="current highlight"></td>
<td class="">1</td>
<td class="htAutocomplete">Each<div class="htAutocompleteArrow">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="">D480 3-STAGE TRUE HEPA AIR PURIFIER</td><td class=""><a class="no-border" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><div class="screen-reader-only">Delete</div></a></td></tr>
```

Any ideas on how to use execute script, setAttribute, or send keys to enter numbers into these td Master Pack boxes?

UPDATE:
I was able to temporarily enter numbers into the box using this code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="asnPick_order_0_itemInfo_TABLE"]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]').click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='htCore']//tbody/tr//td[contains(@class, 'highlight')]")))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "1"', element)
```

When this code runs, it correctly places the number one into the box. However, that number one disappears after I click the next button to save the page. I seems like I am only changing the appearance of this form not actually editing the box because it disappears. Why would editing the innerHTML only be temporary?
Any ideas on how to keep the 1 from disappearing or permanently edit/send the key to the html? Thanks

Here is the html for after the number 1 is added.

```
<td class="current highlight">1</td>
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Any Ideas?

Comment: Why `execute_script()`, anything wrong with `send_keys("1")`? Can you update the question with the text based HTML please?

Comment: I tried the send_keys("1") first but that produced the element not intractable error, I then tried the execute script but could not get it to work, (I could not figure out what attributes I needed to be setting to "1")

Comment: Text based HTML would be of immense help.

Comment: I added the HTML sorry about that

Comment: There are still some discrepency as the image HTML of the element contains the class `current highlight` where as the text HTML contains the class `htInvalid current highlight`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217974/discussion-between-ryan-bobber-and-debanjanb).

Answer (score 0):

To set the value as **1** within the column **MasterPack** for the first row you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `setAttribute()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='htCore']//tbody/tr//td[contains(@class, 'highlight')]")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','1')", element)
  ```
- Using `setValue()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='htCore']//tbody/tr//td[contains(@class, 'highlight')]")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='1';", element)
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)
- [Send keys not working selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770697/send-keys-not-working-selenium-webdriver-python/46773859#46773859)

Comment: This  did not work
No error was produced but it did not update the box.
A new value tag was created in the HTML but no text appeared in the cell
I will send a pic of the html
<td class="current highlight" value="1"></td>

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: That did not work either. Same thing as the first answer. No error but no text was created in the box. A new value tag was created again <td class="current highlight" value="1"></td>

Comment: Is there a way to do a general send_keys command with execute script?

Comment: Also I don't understand why I get a noninteractable error when I try to send keys but the program can successfully click the masterpack cell.

Comment: @RyanBobber In those cases you have update the question with the relevant HTML before and after click. That may help us debug the issue.

Comment: I have reworked the question to include what I have found out so far, what I have tried and some updated HTML. Let me know if you have any idea. Thank you for your help

Comment: I made a little bit of progress today. I added an update portion to the question. Sorry to keep bugging you but if you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: The change in `master pack cell` due to the click is crucial. Unless you explain that as it is, it's gonna be tough to assume whats happening there.